# Is it possible to override typeof()?

Tags: c#, datetime, struct, types

I have a custom struct that have a native type inside, and i want to make it behave like a native type

This is the struct:

```
private struct test
{
    private DateTime Value;

    public test(DateTime value)
    {
       Value = value;
    }           
}
```

I want to this to be true:

```
typeof(test) == typeof(DateTime)
```

Comment: Why? This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/1968).

Comment: What is the actual task or problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: You can implement al sorts of operators to get your class to behave almost like a native type but it will be a different type. And different types will never be equal in a call like yours. You won't get methods to use your type instead of DateTime if they are intended to use DateTime for example. But as is you can implement almost any operator here implementing an implicit cast might achieve what you want.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [FAQ] and [ask] before you go on the website.

Answer (score 5):

`typeof` is not a real method but an operator keyword and it will receive special treatment from the C# compiler. You cannot override or overload it.

You can use implicit conversions instead:

```cs
private struct Test
{
    private DateTime Value;

    public Test(DateTime value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Test(DateTime date) => new Test(date);
    public static implicit operator DateTime(Test test) => test.Value;
}
```

With the implicit conversions you can write code like:

```cs
Test test = DateTime.Now;
DateTime date = test;
```

Use these “magic” conversions carefully, otherwise your code could become difficult to understand.

You can also replace the `implicit` keyword by `explicit` and then write:

```cs
Test test = (Test)DateTime.Now;
DateTime date = (DateTime)test;
```

This better reflects the programmer's intent.

---

If what you want is testing the types, you could also add these static methods to the struct:

```cs
public static bool IsTest(Type t) => t == typeof(Test) || t == typeof(DateTime);
public static bool IsTest<T>() => typeof(T) == typeof(Test) || typeof(T) == typeof(DateTime);
public static bool IsTest<T>(T _) => typeof(T) == typeof(Test) || typeof(T) == typeof(DateTime);
```

They would allow you to perform these tests:

```cs
private void TestMethod<T>()
{
    Test test = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime date = test;

    bool b1 = Test.IsTest(date);
    bool b2 = Test.IsTest(test);
    bool b3 = Test.IsTest<T>();
    bool b4 = Test.IsTest(typeof(DateTime));
    bool b5 = Test.IsTest(typeof(Test));
}
```

It is also possible to [define value equality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-define-value-equality-for-a-type) in different ways as explained in the linked article.